# Symlink from non-existed disk

Tags: symbolic-link, forwarding

I have home PC with tools on disk A.
Now I want to setup my work PC, but I haven`t disk A here.
Unfortunately many tools has hard links to A.

Is there way to symlink all requests from disk A to D on work PC?

Comment: What is the OS? What do you mean by "has hard links to A"? AFAIK hardlinks cannot cross filesystem boundaries, so if there is no disk A then there are no hardlinks to A because they must be on A (but I'm a Linux guy, *maybe* what you wrote has more sense in Windows). I imagine if you install the tools in an existing location then they will work even without A; there should be no issue. So do you want to *copy* the tools and their configs? Please [edit] and clarify.

Comment: Both Windows 10. I guess I used wrong word `hardlinks`. Many tools has hardcoded absolute path to each other like `A:\Tools\SomeFolder`. So I need to put same folder to `D:\Tools` and somehow redirect to D.